# Нужна помощь с задачей!

Tags: javascript, массивы, ecmascript-6

Вот условие: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Моq код:

```
    function allNumsToString(obj){
 var arr = [];
 var result = [];
 for(let key in obj){
     arr.push(obj[key]);
 }
    arr.sort((a,b)=>{
  return a-b;
});
    arr.join(";");
 return arr;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я распишу поэтапно, а вы организуете это всё в функции так, как считаете нужным:

```
const obj = {
   init: 0,
   nums: [111,222,333],
   a: 1,
   b: 11
};

// поучаем все значения свойств 
let vals = Object.values(obj);

// преобразуем в одномерный массив
vals = vals.flat();
// альтернативный способ:
// [].concat(...vals)

// сортировка 
vals.sort();

// объединяет все элементы
vals.join(';');
```

Comment: прошу прощения, забыл добавить, что нужно все это сделать с применением методов для массивов и через цикл

Comment: @Torin_21, методы `flat()`, `concat()`, `sort()` и `join` - это как раз методы для массивов. Остаётся заменить `Object.values()`. Тут и может пригодится цикл, который вы показываете в своём вопросе

Comment: P.S. Только желательно в цикле делать проверку, исключая наследуемые свойства: [hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) (смотрите "*Пример: обход свойств объекта*")

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = []

function test (obj) {
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
        obj[key].forEach(item => {
        arr.push(item)
      })
    } else {
        arr.push(obj[key])
    }
  }
  return arr.sort().join(';')
}

let input = {
  a: 3,
  b: [2, 1]
}

console.log(test(input))
```